# UITableViewCell is not available in XIB file in XCode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode5

I have just encountered a problem today that I am unable to add a new table view cell to my UITableview.

What I did was I drag a table view cell and drop inside the UITableview area. The UITableview did not take the table view cell but rather the cell become an individual view of the main view.

[image: Clearly see that table view cell is not included in Table View]
Clearly see that table view cell is not included in Table View

So my question is, how to create a custom table view cell in UITableview in an XIB file in Xcode 5?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you have dynamic prototype cell will be added automatically. If not, you can choose how much cell you want to have in inspector on right side of screen. 
And make sure when you put it into screen that is inside of your tableview.

Comment: I couldn't find anything relating to the number of cell I want to have under attributes inspector. Where should I look for it? BTW, I did try to include the table view cell inside the tableview. But it just created a new view rather than became a part of table view.

Answer (score 0):

I answer this question thinking you are using storyboard. First add UITableView.
Then you can see as this,
[image]

If you want to use static cell, select Table View & in Attributes Inspector , in content select Static Cells. I think for your question you should use Static Cells.

Comment: I am using .xib rather than storyboard and I am not using table view controller.

Comment: Did you try to use Table View Cell directly without Table View?

Comment: I will try but I have tried to use this table view cell when constructing the table view. The table view didn't use my table view cell at all but rather created a brand new cell(I am using the correct cell identifier)

Comment: Are you using Objectic C Class -> UITableViewController to control the Tabel View & Objectic C Class -> UITableViewCell to control the Cell?

Comment: I am using UIViewcontroller for my entire view with my tableview's delegate properly set and uitableviewdatasource and uitableviewdelegate used. how does this help me to include UITableviewcell to my UITableview?

Comment: you should add those delegate & datasource to tableview,
@interface NAMEOFTHEFILE : UITableViewController <UITabBarDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

Comment: I did. But the problem occurred in the XIB file.

Comment: I am coming to the conclusion that this functionality is only available in storyboards and not xib files (I have no idea why this might be). I have a project which has a storyboard and an xib file, and dragging a table view controller into the storyboard brings it up with a heading "prototype cells" and you can drag cells on to it. Doing the same thing in the xib does not let you add cells. XCode 5.0.2.

Comment: Check out http://mrmaksimize.com/ios/Custom-UITableViewCell-With-NIB/ for a way to do it with xibs